# How to read this code coverage xml file report using c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

**Read this xml file to get the assembly names** and their coverage percentage whose value is less than 95, i need to read the assembly name with less than 95 percent code coverage value, and store the assembly name and coverage percent in an object.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    -<Root DotCoverVersion="2021.1.2" ReportType="Xml" CoveragePercent="97" TotalStatements="108" CoveredStatements="105">
    -<Assembly CoveragePercent="94" TotalStatements="54" CoveredStatements="51" Name="ClassLibrary1">
    -<Namespace CoveragePercent="94" TotalStatements="54" CoveredStatements="51" Name="ClassLibrary1">
    -<Type CoveragePercent="94" TotalStatements="54" CoveredStatements="51" Name="Class1">
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="3" CoveredStatements="3" Name="Add(int,int):int"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="16" CoveredStatements="16" Name="Armstrong(int):string"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="5" CoveredStatements="5" Name="Decision(int):int"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="79" TotalStatements="14" CoveredStatements="11" Name="isApplicable(int):string"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="3" CoveredStatements="3" Name="sub(int,int):int"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="13" CoveredStatements="13" Name="total(int):int"/>
    </Type>
    </Namespace>
    </Assembly>
    -<Assembly CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="54" CoveredStatements="54" Name="UnitTestProject2">
    -<Namespace CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="54" CoveredStatements="54" Name="UnitTestProject2">
    -<Type CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="54" CoveredStatements="54" Name="TestDemo">
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="5" CoveredStatements="5" Name="Test_Add():void"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="5" CoveredStatements="5" Name="Test_Armstrong_False():void"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="5" CoveredStatements="5" Name="Test_Armstrong_InvalidNumber():void"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="5" CoveredStatements="5" Name="Test_Armstrong_True():void"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="5" CoveredStatements="5" Name="Test_Decision_False():void"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="5" CoveredStatements="5" Name="Test_Decision_True():void"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="5" CoveredStatements="5" Name="Test_isApplicable_Applicable():void"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="5" CoveredStatements="5" Name="Test_isApplicable_NotValidAge():void"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="5" CoveredStatements="5" Name="Test_Sub():void"/>
    <Method CoveragePercent="100" TotalStatements="9" CoveredStatements="9" Name="Test_total():void"/>
    </Type>
    </Namespace>
    </Assembly>
    </Root>
```

this is the xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code to use `XDocument` to achieve the assembly name and coverage percentage whose value is less than 95.

```
   string path = "E:\\test.xml";
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(path);
    var result = doc.Descendants("Assembly").Where(i => Convert.ToInt32(i.Attribute("CoveragePercent").Value) < 95);
    foreach (var item in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("CoveragePercent").Value);
        Console.WriteLine(item.Attribute("Name").Value);
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    public class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement xRoot = doc.Root;
            Root root = new Root() {
                DotCoverVersion = (string)xRoot.Attribute("DotCoverVersion"),
                ReportType = (string)xRoot.Attribute("ReportType"),
                CoveragePercent = (int)xRoot.Attribute("CoveragePercent"),
                TotalStatements = (int)xRoot.Attribute("TotalStatements"),
                CoveredStatements  = (int)xRoot.Attribute("CoveredStatements"),
                Level = 0
            };

            Node.GetNodes(xRoot, null, 1);

            List<Node> lowCoverage = Root.Nodes.Where(x => x.CoveragePercent < 95).ToList();
            foreach (Node node in lowCoverage)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name = {0}, Percentage = {1}", node.Name, node.CoveragePercent.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
    public class Root
    {
        public string DotCoverVersion { get; set; }
        public string ReportType { get; set; }
        public int CoveragePercent { get; set; }
        public int TotalStatements { get; set; }
        public int CoveredStatements { get; set; }
        public static List<Node> Nodes = new List<Node>();
        public int Level { get; set; }
    }
    public class Node: Root
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string TagName { get; set; }
        public Node ParentNode { get; set; }

        public static void GetNodes(XElement xParent, Node parentNode, int level)
        {
            foreach (XElement child in xParent.Elements())
            {
                Node newNode = new Node();
                Root.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                newNode.Name = (string)child.Attribute("Name");
                newNode.TagName = child.Name.LocalName;
                newNode.ParentNode = parentNode;
                newNode.Level = level;
                newNode.TotalStatements = (int)child.Attribute("TotalStatements");
                newNode.CoveragePercent = (int)child.Attribute("CoveragePercent");
                newNode.CoveredStatements = (int)child.Attribute("CoveredStatements");
                GetNodes(child, newNode, level + 1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```